# What is /dev/selinux?

Tags: android, selinux, init, ramdisk

Is there a device node called `/dev/selinux`

Android 13 init crashes with the following

```
[    1.417333]  (7)[1:init]selinux: SELinux: Loaded file_contexts
[    1.417341]  (7)[1:init]selinux: 
[    1.419537]  (7)[1:init]selinux: SELinux: Could not set context for /dev/selinux:  Permission denied
[    1.419545]  (7)[1:init]selinux: 
[    1.419623]  (7)[1:init]init: restorecon failed of /dev/selinux failed: Success
[    1.420364]  (7)[1:init]init: InitFatalReboot: signal 6
```

When I run command `ls /dev/selinux` with a stock ramdisk it is absent, when I compile Lineage 20 the ramdisk boots to the permission denied on `/dev/selinux` error

Comment: I have no idea what caused your error. But regarding to what `/dev/selinux` is...: you probably saw https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/selinux.cpp, the source of the SELinux implementation on Android. `/dev/selinux` seems to be present in the "split" implementation of SELinux on Android.